# How to build a machine learning model from sparse features with class imbalance?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, sparse, data-preprocessing

I have around 10 numerical features and 1 class/target (e.g., visitors count of a website). All of them are sparse. Sparsity is around %70-80. The median of the class/target is zero. Is there a good way to build a classifier or regressor for the class/target? In the case of classification I was hoping to use the median as a seperator, but now I am not sure what to use.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. It sounds to me like you don't have a sparsity problem but a problem with imbalanced classes. Am I right?

Comment: @rep_ho thanks, it is both.